# how apply Mysql concat in Propel?

Tags: mysql, orm, where-clause, propel, concatenation

I am trying do a remote filtering of a data grid.

The grid has a textfield, where the user enters chars which are sent to the server to refresh the grid.

My problem is that I am using Propel to work with the database and I need concat two MySQL fields to do the comparison. I don't know how do a simple `where concat(firstname, ',', lastname) like '%aText%'` in Propel.

I've tried:

```
$usuarios = UsuariosQuery::create()
  ->where("(concat(usuarios.apellido,' , ',usuarios.nombre)) LIKE '%?%'",$filter)
  ->orderByApellido('ASC')
  ->find();
```

This doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [according to the doc](http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/WhatsNew) (search for `concat`):

```
$usuarios = UsuariosQuery::create()
  ->where('CONCAT(Usuarios.Apellido, ",", Usuarios.Nombre) LIKE ?', $filter)
  ->orderByApellido('ASC')
  ->find();
}}}
```

Comment: Thanks !! i test your suggestion, and work !. But i wrote the where clause so:
where('CONCAT(Usuarios.Apellido, ",", Usuarios.Nombre) LIKE ?', "%$filter%").